# Filezilla: Transfers files but still can't see site on network

Tags: sftp, filezilla

I am having major Filezilla(SFTP) problems. I have been trying for three days to transfer my files online to my site. It should be simple, but it's not. I am using Filezilla client(1 and 1.com ) as my host on Windows. I have had the following results: Cannot connect to server. Connection closed by server. Timed out. I have tried checking to see if my Port was blocked. I am supposed to use a Port of 22. Changing my password and changing my settings from passive to active and moving my index. HTML directly to my public_html folder. Nothing seems to work.I just really would like to see my site up. Help!

[image]

Comment: so you are connecting successfully with Filezilla, to post the files, but when you try to view those files in a web browser, you get a Cannot connect to server error?

Comment: This isn't an issue with FileZilla or SFTP.. we can see from your screenshot that FileZilla is working and connecting properly (and that you've successfully transferred files)

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be your problem, Your HTML documents are on the server, but not showing up when you navigate to port `80`.

This then becomes a problem with the program that is hosting the files for a web browser (Apache, etc.). I would recommend looking over the documentation for the server that you have set-up, or that came pre-configured, and verifying the directory name and the index name is correct. (Among other settings)

If this doesn't help you, I would recommend contacting the support for One and One.

Hope this Helps!